# Silverlight - tab navigation with arrow keys

Tags: silverlight-4.0, navigation, command, tabs, arrow-keys

How to cycle between controls with arrow keys.

I want the same effect as I get with Tab key.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define order you want then handle ArrowKeys and change focus while pressing arrow keys according to your defined order.

I guess i should work that way.